# Row Number in Symfony Doctrine Query

Tags: php, database, doctrine, symfony-1.4, dql

I am storing data for lap times in a database, the data consists of a distance, time, average speed and max speed.

I am trying to display a leaderboard which shows the top ten people in whatever query you set (who has gone thr furthest in total, best average time etc). However, below the top ten I want to show the user who is logged ins position in the leaderboard. To do this I am trying to run the same query ordering my results and adding a ROW NUMBER to get the position.

I am using symfony 1.4 with the Doctrine ORM and I can't for the life of me figure out how to get row numbers in a query. I know you can do it in SQL like so:

```
SELECT full_name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY distance) AS row_number
```

Yet I can't get it working in Doctrine Symfony.

Does anyone have any ideas on a way I can do this? (or even another way of going about it)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I actually have a solution to this where i hydrate the results into an array, its not the best but it works. Will post it when stack overflow allows me (7 hours)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok heres my solution:

I kind of found an answer to this after some more experimenting and collaborating.

What I did was get rid of the select and just return the ordered list of results;

```
$results = self::getInstance()->createQuery('r')
    ->orderBy('r.distance')
    ->execute();
```

Then I hydrated this result into an array and used array_search() to find the key of the result in the array (luckily I am returning user data here, and I know the user I am looking for in the array)

```
$index = array_search($user->toArray(), $results->toArray());
```

I can then return the **$index + 1** to give me the users position in the leaderboard.

There is probably a better way to do this database side, but I couldn't for the life of me find out how.

If anyone has a better solution then please share.

Comment: This is working, howver, you create overhead using php to get the rank. If your database is very large, you will found performances problems.